# Lengthy Query Time for MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql db with 4 tables that get updated independently. 2 of the tables will have roughly 25k to 35k rows at any given time (bhMacAcct and sv). I have to join various bits from each table.

This is the query I ended up landing on:

```
SELECT bhMacAcct.acct,pkg,sv.mac,sv.recData
FROM bhMacAcct,bhPkgAcct,sv
WHERE (bhMacAcct.acct = bhPkgAcct.acct) AND (bhMacAcct.mac = sv.mac);
```

It takes between 3-5 minutes when using this query. Is there possibly an easier way? Can this be further optimized for speed?

Answer (score 2):

First, always use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax and qualify all column names:

```
SELECT ma.acct, pkg, sv.mac, sv.recData
FROM bhMacAcct ma JOIN
     bhPkgAcct pa
     ON ma.acct = pa.acct JOIN
     sv
     ON ma.mac = sv.mac;
```

For this query, start with indexes on all the columns used for joins.  I would recommend:  `bhMacAcct(acct, mac)`, `bhPkgAcct(acct)`, and `sv(mac, recData)`.  I would also put `pkg` in the appropriate index, so the indexes cover the query.